# JqPlot - Does not show simple graph

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I'm really new to Javascrip/Jquery/Jqplot and I'm trying to learn by myself.
Then I have some questions,
Is this code enough to show a simple graph? Because it's not working, it shows a blank page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.jqplot.css" />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jqplot.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jqplot.ohlcRenderer.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jqplot.highlighter.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jqplot.cursor.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/customCandlestick.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        document.write("<p>It works!!!</p>");
        var plot1 = $.jqplot ('chart1', [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]]);
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="chart1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used this library too for a project, its really good!.. i just check the example that you post it and i found out what it was causing you an error, you only need to change the document.write sentence, if you use for example the console.log function it will work.

ex.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        console.log("It works!!!");
        var plot1 = $.jqplot ('chart1', [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]]);
    });
```

Another thing important is that this library uses jquery, so you will need to reference all the js files of jqplot after the jquery reference to avoid the JQuery no defined error.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove

```
document.write('<p>It works!!!</p>');
```

Or replace it by

```
document.write('<p>It works!!!</p><div id="chart1"></div>');
```

Your **document.write** statement is replacing the body part of your html page by what you have mentionned (here '< p >It works!< / p >).

Thus your html page isn't containing any div with "chart1" id anymore.
As you specify to jqplot to plot your graphic in a div identified with "chart1" (and document.write statement has erased it) it is a normal behaviour not to be able to see your graphic.

**PS** : It is not compulsory to include all off jqplot plugins to draw your graph. If it will not became more complicated, I suggest you to include only "css/jquery.jqplot.css" and "js/jquery.jqplot.js".
For more complicated graph, include only necessary plugins (for example "js/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.js" if you need to work with date axis).

**Edit**

Please see working jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/7BBFy/1/.), try to play with the two "document.write" lines (try to comment and uncomment them).